# Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI cannot load static files of Django

Tags: html, django, dialogflow-es, chatbot, django-staticfiles

I am trying to complete the official google demo about Dialogflow.
https://github.com/priyankavergadia/Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI

Home.html cannot load static files, and I cannot figure out why.

Please help!

I am continuously getting the error message like;

GET file:///User/Django-Dialogflow-GoogleVisionAPI/chat/templates/%7B%%20static%20'css/bootstrap.css'%20%%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

and I tried to search for the similar error, but not enough resources can be found on the internet.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django Dialogflow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header text-center">
        <h1>Dialogflow</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
          <ul class="list-group js-chat-log">
          </ul>            

          <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control js-text" placeholder="Type something to begin..."/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">   
              <button class="btn btn-primary js-say">Submit</button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file" id="inputGroupFile01"
                    aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/js.cookie.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
      var $chatlog = $('.js-chat-log');
      var $input = $('.js-text');
      
      var $sayButton = $('.js-say');
      var dialogflowUrl = '{% url "index" %}';
      var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

      function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }

      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        }
      });

      var file_length_bool = true;
      // helper method to create the list of inputs and outputs to display on the web page to show the chat messages. 
      function createRow(input) {
        var $row = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');
        var list = '<li class="list-group-item">'
        file_length = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile01').files.length
        if (file_length != 0 && file_length_bool == true){
          filename = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile01').files[0].name
          url_test = "https://storage.googleapis.com/as-testing-bucket/" + filename;
          list +=  '<img src="'+url_test+'" height="100" width="80"/>' + "<br />"
          file_length_bool = false;
        }
        else{
          var k = input.split("\n")
          for(i=0;i<k.length;i++) {
             list += k[i]+"<br />"
          }
        }
          list = list + "</li>"
          $row.text(list);
          $chatlog.append(list);
      }

      window.onload = createRow('<b><font size="4" face="Lucida Console">Chat with Dialogflow</font></b>');

      function submitInput() {

        var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile01');
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        // handle when the user input is text 
        if (file == undefined){
          console.log("No input file");
          var inputData = {
            'text': $input.val(),
          }
          // Display the user's input on the web page
          createRow(inputData.text);
          var dialogflowChatUrl = '{% url "chat-home" %}';
          var $submit = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: dialogflowChatUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(inputData),
            contentType: 'application/json',
          });
        }
        else{
          // handle when input is a file
          var formData = new FormData(file);
          formData.append('file', file);
          // Display the user's input file on the web page
          createRow(formData);
          console.log('Form Data is', formData)
          var dialogflowChatUrl = '{% url "chat-home" %}';
          var $submit = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: dialogflowChatUrl,
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            async:false,
            processData: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
          });
        }

        $submit.done(function(statement) {
            createRow(statement);
            // Clear the input field
            $input.val('');
        });

        $submit.fail(function() {
          // TODO: Handle errors
          console.log('failed')
        });
      }

      $sayButton.click(function() {
        submitInput();
      });

      $input.keydown(function(event) {
        // Submit the input when the enter button is pressed
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          submitInput();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information you have given, the reason static files are not working is because your browser is loading up old static files.

All browsers attempt to keep local copies of static assets in an effort to reduce page load times and minimize network traffic.

You need to refresh your browser cache and that should do it.

For windows

- Hold down ctrl and press the reload button on your browser
- Use F5 and ctrl to refresh the browser

To read more about caching [Guide to Browser Caching](https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. But I still can’t load the static files.

Comment: It's really hard to tell with the information you've given. Could be a file error or a namespace error. Can you show how the dir looks like and if it matches the file you are looking for. Maybe try a different browser and copy all your files to a new directory, whatever helps.